# Matrix of Toggles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I buy a matrix of toggles with the following code:

```
    int amount = 27;
    string[] keywords = new string[amount];
    bool kws[]= new bool[amount];
    for(int i=0;i<amount;i++)
       keywords[i]=""+i;
    int columns = 7;
    int rows = 4;
    int index=0;
    int y=30+30* index;
    int x=0;
    int element=0;
    foreach(string kw in keywords){
        element++;
        if(kws [index] = GUI.Toggle (new Rect (x, y, 100, 30), kws [index], kw)){
            Debug.Log("Selected: "+kw);
        }
        index++;
        x+=100;
        if(element>rows){
            //Reset for the next row
            x=0;
            element=0;
            y+=30;
        }
    }
```

But when I click on the toggles a different one shows as selected. It seems to be in a per block basis. I can't still figure out where's the flaw as each toggle is assigned to a different kws holding the state of it.

Maybe a C#/Unity wiz can pinpoint the issue from miles away.

I guess the real question is:

How to display and keep track of a series of Toggles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my go at it:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    string[] keywords;
    bool[] kws;

    void Awake()
    {
        int amount = 27;
        keywords = new string[amount];
        kws = new bool[amount];
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) keywords[i] = "" + i;
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        int columns = 4;
        int x, y;
        for (int index = 0; index < keywords.Length; index++)
        {
            x = 100 * (index % columns);
            y =  30 * (index / columns) + 30;
            bool oldValue = kws[index];
            kws[index] = GUI.Toggle(new Rect (x, y, 100, 30), kws[index], keywords[index]);
            if (kws[index] != oldValue)
            {
                Debug.Log("Switched: " + keywords[index] + " to " + kws[index]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The most important thing is that you should separate the initialization and use, because in your original version the toggle states are reset every time and pressing the buttons will have no lasting effect.

Second, using a foreach loop only to jump through hoops to keep track of which bool goes along with it is a bad idea. If the keywords and kws array truly are inseparable you might want to create a class or struct that holds a string and a bool just so they are together at all times. What i show here is the next best thing. If you find one according to its index, you should use that same index to find the other.

Finally i put an often seen trick in there to get the grid layout. Again the place in the grid is purely driven by its index. You will often see % (modulo) and / (division) being used together like that.

Comment: The location didn't work (x,y) as there were a bunch on top of each other, but besides that, the main issue was still present. I'll Keep playing with it. The initialization is done once already, just added it here for the example.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to tell what you're trying to do. Maybe something like this?

```
const int amount = 27;
bool[] kws = new bool[amount];

void OnGUI()
{
    string[] keywords = new string[amount];
    for(int i=0;i<amount;i++)
        keywords[i]=""+i;
    int columns = 7;
    int rows = 4;
    int index=0;
    int y=30+30* index;
    int x=0;
    int element=0;
    foreach(string kw in keywords){
        element++;
        bool selected = GUI.Toggle (new Rect (x, y, 100, 30), kws [index], kw);
        if(selected && !kws [index])
        {
            Debug.Log("Selected: "+kw);
        }
        kws[index] = selected;
        index++;
        x+=100;
        if(element>rows){
            //Reset for the next row
            x=0;
            element=0;
            y+=30;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically this is what I'm doing, just giving a different bool for each Toggle. You are initializing them to kws[index] but not tracking further changes.